# Getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown at me when running Spark inside Docker

Tags: apache-spark, docker, jvm

I'm trying to run a Spark instance within Docker and am frequently getting this exception thrown:

```
16/10/30 23:20:26 ERROR SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[Executor task launch worker-1,5,main]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
```

I'm using this Docker image https://github.com/sequenceiq/docker-spark.

My ulimits seem ok inside the container:

```
bash-4.1# ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 29747
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1048576
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 1048576
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

They also look good outside the container, on the host:

```
kane@thinkpad ~> ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 29747
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 29747
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

My Googling told me that systemd can limit the tasks and cause this issue, but I've got my task limit set to infinity:

```
kane@thinkpad ~> grep TasksMax /usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service 
20:TasksMax=infinity

kane@thinkpad ~> systemctl status docker
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2016-10-31 08:22:39 AWST; 3h 14min ago
     Docs: http://docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 1107 (docker-current)
    Tasks: 56
   Memory: 34.9M
      CPU: 30.292s
```

Any ideas? My Spark code is simply reading from a Kafka instance (running in a separate Docker container) and doing a basic map/reduce. Nothing fancy.

Comment: Could you please post the docker commands you are using?

Answer (score 0):

The error states that you can't create more native thread because you don't have enough memory. it doesn't necessarily mean you reach the ulimits but you don't have enough memory to create more thread.

The memory size to create a thread in a JVM is controlled by the -XSS Flag and is 1024k by default if i remember correctly. If you don't have a lot of recursive call, you may try to decrease the XSS flag and be able to create more thread with the same amount of memory available. If the XSS is too small, you will encounter a StackOverFlowError

The docker-spark image use the hadoop-docker image which contains an HDFS and Yarn service
You may allocate too much memory from your container for your JVMs heap size (hdfs, yarns),  and therefore there is not enough memory remaining to allocate new thread.

Hope it'll help